# HelixWpf Rotating Label

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit

I made a WPF application which render a panel that might have different texture on each side.

The model is free of rotation over all axes.
My boss asked me if would be possible to identify each panel side with a label (one digit for each side) and let it rotate with the panel... but sincerely I dunno how to achieve this, expecally to keep each label "in front" of the view point.

Any hints?

[image: plate picture]

Comment: Do you mean you want the labels are not always facing the screen? Or you just want to create some billboards?

Comment: Yes, I mean that the labels should be facing to the screen

Comment: Billboards should be what you need.

Comment: Hi @LanceH, I've been able to create those labels using billboardtextvisual3d. Just a question: is it correct the each label are always front of camera and does not take care of other 3d objects (such my panel)?

Comment: Billboard is not always in front of other objects. If you want to achieve this, you have to use double viewports with HelixToolkit.WPF. Or you need to switch to use HelixToolkit.WPF.SharpDX.

Comment: This is interesting, I didn't know that it was necessary two viewports for this thing.